# How should I UV a highly detailed building?

Tags: uv

I have several versions of the same medium sized building for use in unreal engine. I have one where all the walls are a single object, and one where the walls are broken apart into separate objects.

Several different materials are to be applied to the building walls. I already fully UV mapped the version where the walls are one object but this took forever lining up several materials onto one UV channel. There must be a better way to do this.

That's why I have the separate wall version but this is also difficult to line up the textures just right when they are different objects.

Any advice on what to do would be appreciated thank you :)

Comment: Please add some screenshots of this wall or for better answer upload stripped down blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/